# How to define heading tags hierarchy for complex website

Tags: html, tags, seo, hierarchy

I need advice to design the best possible heading tags with respect to SEO optimization and with good results.

**RED** menu is main menu. Is still visible and the same.
**BLUE** menu is submenu
**MAGENTA** is visible only under certain circumstances
**GREEN** is title for section, list or item etc.

Here are possible scenarios:

[image]

Which would be better?

```
<h1> for RED, <h2> for BLUE, <h3> for MAGENTA and <h4> for GREEN
```

or

```
<h4> for RED, <h3> for BLUE, <h2> for MAGENTA and <h1> for GREEN
```

Thank you for the clarification

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming.

Comment: Then try create perfect optimized web page for SEO without programming. :) Of course is just about right programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of two proposed solutions is actually correct usage of heading elements.
So it will not be useful in SEO either.
Like it's said [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements)

> Heading elements implement six levels of document headings, `<h1>` is the most important and `<h6>` is the least. A heading element briefly describes the topic of the section it introduces.

Use heading elements for what they are created.
If you use them just to boost SEO on wrong data/elements you can just make it worse.
Lot of people already tried that (and still trying) and don't think that their intents are not recognized by search engines.
Like John Mueller from Google said [here](https://youtu.be/i_xnKznRNCc?t=2661), heading gives a slight boost to page if there is clear and correct heading regarding topic but extensive usage is not recommended.

So in your case **red**, **blue** and **magenta** are menus so use some standard navigation elements that you would use anyway. Adding heading elements there, in my opinion, is counterproductive.

But **green** is good candidate for heading tag. I would say `<h1>` but it depends on rest of content and type of page.
For example product title on ebay product page is in `<h1>` tag and your bottom right page looks like good candidate for that.

Comment: Completely agree with you, it's far too often that headings are over used.

Comment: thank you. i look ebay source. yes h1 is used for titles in whole structure on page. but h3 is used as titles for each item in list everywhere.. and h2 is used on menu elements which is not visible for user. not understand :) i need only correct understand usability, not boost or over use h tags.

Comment: Yes I see that some menus are in h2 tags on ebay. I wouldn't do that, but again this is just my opinion having in mind suggestions from google. For me, correct usage is describing text content on page something like this `<h1>Earth</h1><h2>Europe</h2><h3>Croatia</h3>` etc.. Although, in my experience, in most cases you won't need to go deeper that `<h3>` or `<h4>`. So set it by importance to describe content and suggestions are to use `<h1>` tag just once on page. So if you have 'Earth' page there is no need to set `<h1>Earth</h1>` multiple times. Other h tags are fine to repeat.